# Get how many times a given pattern are matched in vim

Tags: vim

I an use `/pattern` to match patterns in the current file, is there a way to show many many matches there are after I hit enter for previous search command? Then I will have a sense that how many navigation to do to go through all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a simple mapping that prints the number of matches:

```
:nnoremap <A-n> :%s///gn<CR>
41 matches on 17 lines
```

My [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) provides a more elaborate variant of this:

```
1 match after cursor in this line, 8 following, 2 in previous lines;
total 10 within 11,42 for /\<SearchPosition\>/
```

There's also the [IndexedSearch plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1682), which integrates the reporting with the n / N commands.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `/pattern`, you could use:

```
:vim /pattern % | cw
```

to open a list of matches in the quickfix window.

You can also use:

```
:il[ist] /pattern/
```

and choose from the list with:

```
:{line number}
```